# Japanese and chinese characters are not abiding by the site responsive outline

Tags: wordpress, translation

Articles of these two langueges are striking out of the responsive layout in wordpress.While korean language has no problem. I believe it's because the characters are not recognized?

I checked my database is in utf-8. I tried installing polylang a plugin to translate properly, but doesnt help.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you please check your header?
screen-shot: https://screencast.com/t/AVFFIX9wV
did you add <meta charset="utf-8" /> in head tag?

Comment: yes it has <meta charset="utf-8">